# not able to generate json data using spring3 restful

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, restful-url

HI All i am new to spring restful service.i am trying to expose one of my method as restful and i am getting the xml data from this url(localhost:7001/SpringRestService/restful/showAllGrants/ALL/ALL/ALL/ALL.xml)
    but when i type (localhost:7001/SpringRestService/restful/showAllGrants/ITSMAXK/ALL/ALL/ALL.json) in order to get json data then i am getting below error.

---------------------error on web page-------------------------------

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: isEnabled
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView.renderMergedOutputModel(MappingJacksonJsonView.java:240)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:917)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:813)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:798)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:226)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:124)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3370)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Lweblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject;Lweblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject;Ljava.security.PrivilegedAction;)Ljava.lang.Object;(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2117)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2023)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1359)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

below is my code which i am using

----------------------------------applicationContext.xml------------------

application context file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes-->
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.nea.rest.unsr" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.nea.spring.services.implementations.Uniserv" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.nea.spring.services.interfaces.uniservs" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.nea.ia.services.util.uniserv" />

<bean id="uniservService"  class="org.spring.services.implementations" />



    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <map>
                                <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
                                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
                            </map>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>                
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />               
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
                            <property name="classesToBeBound">
                                <list>
                                    <value>org</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>



<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only! -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>

-------------------------------jsp page---------------------------------
```

Jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring restful service</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>testing server</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which Spring Web MVC version?

Comment: Seems to me you have an old version of Jackson in your POM. 2.0.6 works fine for me. Are you sure you're using Spring 3.0, as the context file refers to?